# how do I validate a field against an enum of strings in typescript nestjs

Tags: typescript, validation, enums, nestjs, dto

I have an Enum of timezones as shown below

```
export enum Timezones  {
    'Europe/Andorra',
    'Asia/Dubai',
    'Asia/Kabul',
    'America/Antigua'
}
```

and in the DTO file I'm validating timezone field against the Enum as shown below

```
  @IsEnum(Timezones, { each: true })
  timezone: string;
```

but validation is not working and is accepting other values as well.

Comment: Shouldnt your DTO have this `@IsEnum(Timezones, { each: true })
  timezone: Timezones[];`

Comment: hi @ShaunakD, yes tried that as well, but its not working,

in my request JSON I sent 
```
{
"timezone": "Europe/xyz",
}
```
its not validating

Comment: `each: true` is used for array.

Comment: yes, its still not working

Answer (score 0):

this enum

```
export enum Timezones  {
    'Europe/Andorra',
    'Asia/Dubai',
    'Asia/Kabul',
    'America/Antigua'
}
```

is interpreted as shown

```
export enum Timezones  {
    0 : 'Europe/Andorra',
    1 : 'Asia/Dubai',
    2 : 'Asia/Kabul',
    3 : 'America/Antigua'
}
```

so you are actually validating against the indices 0,1,2,3...
im not sure ho to fix this